# Selective downloading of torrents via webseeding

Tags: java, http, jetty, p2p, libtorrent

I serve up files from a Jetty webserver which presently get downloaded via regular HTTP GET.

However, I am interested in a P2P model where users can download files via the webseeding. How would this be implemented in the context of a Jetty server with libtorrent?

Second, I dont want to "seed" ALL files on the Jetty webserver forever, instead I only want to be able to seed files "on demand". 
For example rather than blindly seeding a torrent, I would like to have the file available for demand IF a request comes in for it (via GET or webseeding or whatever) - upon which it can be "seeded".

I want to seed or upload on demand because I have a multitude of files and do not know if I will be able to seed tens of thousands of files concurrently. Btw would anyone know what the upper limit is for number of files which can be seeded concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant documentation about the libtorrent part is here: http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html#http-seeding and the specs are http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0019.html and http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0017.html (both being supported by libtorrent, as "url seeds" and "http seeds").

IIRC, BEP19 (webseeds, or urlseeds) is rather straight-forward from the server POV, and you don't need to do anything special there - you *just serve the files as you would do for a normal HTTP requests for that file* (so, the second part of your question doesn't quite make sense here).

With BEP17, you rather use a unique http endpoint, and pass it get parameters to specify what the client wants (which for example allows for better throttling control and range selection) (eg: http://example.com/seed/?info_hash=X&piece=Y&ranges=Z).

This second approach is more flexible if you intend to have more (programmatic) control over what is downloaded, but obviously requires a lot more code to write to handle the requests though.

Again, from the server POV, this is not that different from regular HTTP transactions, and there is nothing special about "seeding" here. You just serve files (each with its own url, either directly, or via a handler).

A for the metadata part, with BEP19, you add a "url-list" extension (with the full url of your file: http://example.com/seeds/SOMEFILE.txt - watch out for multi-file torrents), whereas BEP17 uses the key "httpseeds" (with your endpoint, eg: http://example.com/seed/).

Depending on whether your Jetty also handle metadata generation or not, you might prefer BEP19 over BEP17, for your urls to be more predictable / the metadata generation to be simpler...

Hope that helps.